# Is it possible to change camera view while recording video in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, video-recording

Basically my app use to play and record the video by user selection. while recording the video I need to change the camera view to front or back view. I know it's not possible with `UIImagePickerController`.

Could any one please suggest me with any best solution for this issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible.

for an example - take the native iphone camera app. you cannot change the camera once you start with recording...

though is you use **AVCaptureSession** to record from within the app and you are writing video via **AVAssetWriter**, this will look feasible but you have to handle whole recording by yourself however, the video stream will crack and resume (to stop stream from one camera and start stream from other) when you will switch cameras so you will not have seamless video recording experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app (can't remember the name) that records both cameras at the same time.

Using this you should be able to (at the least) set both recording but only show one view. Then swap out the view at the press of a button.

Or just show both views and allow the user to edit at the end?